# Reference each sub group of data by group name

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I will be working will some data where each item is part of a sub group (see sample data) and i need to be able to reference these sub groups of data but without filtering and naming each one as there will be dozens of sub groups which can change over time, so i am looking to create a data set for each unique sub group.

I have the following which works for sub group 'A.1' with my sample data. But I'm looing to be able to create group_x.y for each of the subgroups (11 in this case).

Data:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(Group=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), each=4),
                 SubGroup=c('A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'A.1', 'B.1', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'B.2', 'C.1', 'C.2', 'C.2', 'C.2', 'D.1', 'D.2', 'D.3', 'D.4'),
                 score=round(runif(16, 0, 1),2),
                 wgt=rep(1/16,16),
                 id=1:16)
```

Example for Sub Group A.1:

```
sub1 <- filter(df, SubGroup %in% 'A.1')
A.1 <- as.matrix(sub1$id)
score <- as.matrix(t(df$score))

group_A.1 <- group_constraint(score, index = c(A.1), dir = ">=", rhs = 0.15)
```

When I use group_A.1 later in my code it works as intended, but i want to be able to automate the steps above to create group_A.1, group_A.2, ..., Group_D.4 etc for each of my sub groups without having to refer to the sub group names.

I have tried using `sub_list <- list(unique(df$SubGroup))` and then some sort of For Each loop on the list but don't seem to be getting anywhere with it.

Edit to include the below code for the group constrain function:

```
full_invest <- L_constraint(rep(1, 16), "==", 1)
group_constraint <- function(r_mat, index, coef.index = 1, dir = "==", rhs) {
  N <- NCOL(r_mat)
  L <- rep(0, N)
  L[index] <- coef.index
  L_constraint(L = L, dir = dir, rhs = rhs)
}

LP <- OP(objective = score,
        rbind(full_invest, group_A.1),
                        maximum = TRUE)
sol1 <- ROI_solve(LP, solver = "glpk")
sol1
x <- solution(sol1)
x
```

Comment: not totally clear to me what you're after, but maybe you want split()?

Answer (score 0):

I would split each subgroup into its own dataframe using `group_split`, which will put them into a list, then you can apply a function to each subgroup with `purrr` (or with `lapply`).

```
library(tidyverse)

grp_constraint <- function(x) {
  group_constraint(
    as.matrix(t(x$score)),
    index = c(as.matrix(x$id)),
    dir = ">=",
    rhs = 0.15
  )
}

purrr::map(group_split(df, SubGroup), grp_constraint)
```

*Note: I wasn't able to get `group_constraint` from `PortfolioAnalytics` to load, so could not test that part.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using `by_Group <- df %>% group_split(SubGroup)` and then `purrr::map(by_Group, group_constraint)`, but am getting an error here.
I'm using the ROI package with install.packages("ROI.plugin.glpk").
I'll edit my original post to include the relevant bits of code if that would help as i think the solution you provided should work if i can figure it out.